# Show a component in all screens with React-Navigation - React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I want to have a component like button (or react-native-action-button precisely) to be shown in each screen using React Navigation.

Does React Navigation has any option in inside Routes to implement it once and use everywhere?

Note: I don't want to import Component in each .js class and use it in render.

Reference -> Like this in app's each screen.
[Floating Action Button Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKPcH.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your Navigation Container add it like this`

```
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
     ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
    
    <Button /> // add your component here. It will be visible in all screens
  </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: sir , do you know how to dynamically change the props of the Button component from any screen?

Comment: Are you trying to change props of this Button component with different screens? . If so, I can only think of achieving this by using Emitters in different screens and receiving those in button component and rendering button accordingly. But I recommend you not to use this method (unless your case is peculiar) as this slows down your application and makes it not smooth.

Comment: I was looking for a way to (for example ) : hide/show the button from any screen or component. I'm trying to implement it using redux at the moment

Comment: It's work but, How can i navigatite to another screen on button click ????

because I unable to pass `navigation` props in button component

Comment: this solution worked for me very fine, since I added a development badge (that appears on all screens in the development staging),
- but I have an issue that this badge does not appear when a Modal is rendered
since the react native Modal comes in the first layer that is shown to the user, 
what to do in this case?!

Answer (score 1):

Make a default screen with that button. Everytime when you want to use that button wrap your all items with that component instead of view.
For example 'DefaultScreen' is your view with the default component. Use it like that:

```
render(){
  <DefaulScreen>
    {AllOtherItems}
  </DefaulScreen>
}
```

And in that DefaultScreen render all children like this:

```
class DefaultScreen extends Component {
  render(){
    <View>
     {this.props.children}
     {defaultComponentThatYouWantToPutWithCustomStyle}
    </View>
  }
}
```

Comment: I would still need to import the DefaultScreen component into my every file and need to replace View with DefaultScreen in existing classes as well. I had done that previously but I was searching for something like 'headerLeft' and 'headerRight' properties in React-Navigation. Where I don't need to write anything in Component classes separately.

Comment: If you use react navigation in your app. You can set your header once and use it everywhere.

Comment: I don't want to implement floating action button into the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your main app navigator in a container component. This container component can have your component which will be displayed on every screen.