# Use an image on multiple screens react native with react navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I want to be able to use an image on multiple screens in react native. For example, when the home screen and settings are loaded I want to use an image on both screens, so that it avoids a re-render when switching screens.

[settingsScreens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml94K.png)

```
<NavigationContainer>
   <Routes/>
</NavigationContainer>
```

where can I insert the image so that it appears on both screens?

Comment: react-native is ia javascript library. how is the question related to java?

Comment: @Turing85 srry br

Comment: @MatheusSantana you mean like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051341/show-a-component-in-all-screens-with-react-navigation-react-native/64167611#64167611

Comment: @sandarshnaroju yes but i still can't

Comment: What about <BackgroundImage /> component to use Image Background in React-Native. But I don't think it avoid re-render when switch screens.